# Autoit GUICtrlRead not returning the value

Tags: autoit

as i said `Global $myVar = GUICtrlRead($myList)` is not returning the selected content of the list, instead its returning the *controlID* of the list, and i decraled the *$myList* variable at the time of creation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are we talking about a list, or a list*view*. Quite different controls. This code works fine: http://pastie.org/9803511

Comment: @Matt We are talking about list (combo box)

Comment: My code posted above works as expected for both lists and combos. What is it that you are doing differently?

Comment: This question was a coding mistake of the asker, which he has not explained or given any reason behind. No help to anyone at all and a waste of at least 3 different peoples time, now yours as well (sorry).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP has indicated on the autoit web site that this was a user problem and has been corrected.

[Forum Post](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/166451-guictrlread-broken/)